# GIS Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- GIS Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- GIS Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### T-Shirt

[image: gis.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### Sticker

[image: gis.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580) — direct links to [sharpie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580), [pens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580), [stickers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Hope it arrives soon (The postal workers are striking here in Canada)

Comment: @jakub it'll be about 6-8 weeks, seriously, as we have a lot of printing and shipping to do. But you'll get it!

Comment: This is really cool, usually you just get a thank you for being helpful...

Comment: Should I still be waiting? almost 4 mnths since I filled out the form. just wondrin. neither kind have I seen.

Comment: yeah for me! IT ARRIVED.

Comment: Thanks for the Awesome package. :)

Comment: If only I knew about this site a few months earlier! This is awesome swag.

Comment: Any plans to do this again?  Just got on the 2nd page! :)

Comment: I guess the SE store is closed. Is that for good? Need new GIS.se stickers and swag.

Comment: @BradNesom ask your friendly neighborhood moderator!

Answer (score 7):

Got my wardrobe set for the first day of classes :)

Answer (score 5):

Received my 'StackExchange' T-Shirt - though I thought would be the GIS StackExchange T-shirt (as above) it was white (ordered Black) and is large (ordered medium).
Not complaining (after all is freebie swag) just a pointer and wandered if others got what they wanted?

Comment: mapperz that is swag from the moderator election, not the GIS swag. There is even MORE swag coming. I'll follow up on the moderator swag shipping error.

Comment: @jeff same here, I received a generic stack exchange shirt but not the GIS swag. And like Mapperz, I'm not complaining about free stuff, just sending the message back to home base.

Comment: @matt wilkie I was told it [StackExchange white T-Shirt] was for being a moderator (which you were and still are in my book) but I was sure I was signing up for a GISse-T-Shirt - got told I had ordered different  to what I had put in the spreadsheet - but free swag is free swag. The confusion is there are 2 different freebies going on at the same time. Still not complaining and wearing what I got.

Comment: Still no GIS SE T-shirt swag - the SE one is fine though.

Answer (score 4):

Got the package today. The shirt looks great. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 3):

@Jeff Atwood, Like Steve, not that it is a big deal at all but just wondering if it is ever coming - Haven't got it yet...(OF COURSE, I forgot to mention (THANKS, DAN) supposed destination: ISRAEL))

Answer (score 3):

No swag either .... Canadian destination but we had a postal strike ... don't want to have to resort to an esri hat for the first day of classes :)

Answer (score 2):

Still haven't gotten mine - not that it is a big deal but just wondering if it is every coming

Comment: 6-8 weeks from the date posted.

Comment: @jeff, thanks. Sorry for missing your earlier comment which says the same thing.

Comment: @jeff, it's nigh on 11 weeks now. I'll not say anything after this as I don't want to be complaining about free stuff, but think you should still be aprised of the ongoing shipping problems. Cheers.

Comment: @matt there were some delays, but they should be going out soon.

Comment: @jeff ok, thanks for the status update

Comment: got a snazzy gis.se shirt and some pens in the mail today. many thanks @jeff and team!!

Answer (score 2):

Got my package today! International delivery didn't take as long as I expected.

Comment: Got mine yesterday. Obviously it takes longer to get to Canada! Thanks very much to whoever I need to thank! I will wear the shirt with pride.

Answer (score 2):

Got my shirt and stuff. Thanks. Unfortunately the logo on the shirt only lasted 1 wash and dry cycle. Now i have a big white dot instead of the nice compass.

Comment: Wash inside out in cold water, hang to dry :)

Comment: I should have realized that such fine shirt requires a lot of TLC. I've downgraded the shirt from favorite to the bottom "work shirt" drawer.

Comment: @Jakub we will send you another one. The shirt was digitally printed on a black T so it requires a bit extra caring than usual. We included some washing instruction in the swag package I believe. Basically, turn it inside out, wash with cold water, no bleach. You will get a new shirt soon!

Comment: Thanks. My package was ripped opened so instructions probably fell out en route. Overzealous scissors happy customs officers probably. Never though we would be having a discussion about washing clothes here...

Answer (score 2):

Got mine about a week ago; thanks to the StackExchange folks!

Answer (score 2):

I just received it! Thanks. My colleagues will be jealous.

Comment: and my bike proud (with the stickers)

Answer (score 2):

You know, I never got my schwag and I was looking forward to wearing it proudly at the next [GeoMeetup](http://www.meetup.com/geomeetup/) :(

UPDATE: I moved! How do I change my address?

Comment: I just emailed my new address via the contact us link at the bottom of the page (they sent it right away after I contacted them as well!)

Answer (score 2):

i still don't have mine :(
 Is there a possibility that something went wrong?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
**I received it today! Very nice! I can't wait to show it to everybody. ;) Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to get mine :( Maybe it got lost in the post, or someone at Australia post stole it