# Washing GIS.se T-shirt

Tags: discussion, announcements, swag

Some of you have received your [swag packages](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/gis-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users). Grats!

I just want to stress that, when you wash your GIS.se t-shirt, **PLEASE** make sure you turn it inside out, use cold water and non-bleach detergent. We used digital printing on the black T, so it requires extra care.

We have received a few reports from our gaming.se community that the design faded after one wash.(which isn't normal, since my gaming shirt looks fine after many washes). Anyway, just want to bring this to your attention.

Comment: This has been noted in this thread within its comments
http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/503/gis-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users
line drying works best :)

Comment: I can confirm that washing it without turning it inside out bleaches colour off the print.   My fault for not reading.   Thanks, still looks good enough for my wardrobe :)